# Typescript: downcast on "this" is not possible

Tags: typescript, casting

In following example TypeScript compiler doesn't allow to cast *this* to *Child* directly. Indeed it is possible using intermediate variable temp or double casting as shown in the commented lines. 
Is it a bug or is there any logical explanation?
The link to [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%09prop%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%09castToChild()%3A%20Child%7B%0D%0A%09%09let%20temp%3A%20Parent%20%3D%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%20as%20Child%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Freturn%20temp%20as%20Child%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Freturn%20temp%20as%20Parent%20Child%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%7B%0D%0A%09otherProp%3A%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%7D)

```
    class Parent {
        prop: string = null;
        castToChild(): Child{
            let temp: Parent = this;
            return this as Child;
            //return temp as Child;
            //return this as Parent as Child;
        }
    }
    class Child extends Parent
    {
        otherProp: string = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly cast a `Parent` to a `Child` simply because the compiler has no way to know that your `Parent` instance really is a `Child`. Use a type guard instead of a cast:

```
class Parent {
    prop: string|null = null;
    isChild(): this is Child {
        return (this as any).otherProp !== undefined;
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    otherProp: string|null = null;
}

function test(p: Parent) {
  if (p.isChild()) {
    console.log(p.otherProp);
  }
}
```

Inside the guarded `if` the compiler now knows that `p` is a `Child`, outside it `p` is still just a `Parent`.

Or better still, override the guard in the subclass and you can avoid doing any typecasting at all:

```
class Parent {
    prop: string|null = null;
    isChild(): this is Child {
        return false;
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    otherProp: string|null = null;
    isChild(): this is Child { return true; }
}

function test(p: Parent) {
  if (p.isChild()) {
    console.log(p.otherProp);
  }
}
```

You are correct however that I haven't answered the question whether this is a bug or deliberate on the part of the Typescript authors. My guess is that they're trying to catch possible errors, but I haven't managed to find explanation of this exact behaviour that would confirm or deny it.

Another way you can make your original code work is to explicitly tell typescript the type of `this` in the `castToChild` method:

```
class Parent {
    prop: string|null = null;

    castToChild(this: Parent): Child{
        return this as Child;
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    otherProp: string|null = null;
}

function foo() {
  let p: Parent = new Child();
  let c = p.castToChild();
  console.log(c.otherProp);
}
```

This is still really just doing the double cast, but perhaps looks a bit cleaner. It does however still show the strangeness of the behaviour as without the explicit `this` parameter `this` is of type `Parent` but not directly castable, with the explicit parameter you can cast it.

Comment: Sorry, but I see your solution as too complicated. My workarounds with having intermediate variable or using double-cast are much shorter and don't require additional code. But they produce just unnecessary syntactical noise. I agree that the the compiler  doesn't know that the Parent is really a Child, but this is exactly the reason why I do casting - to tell that **I** know it better.

Comment: Interesting view. Surely the point of using typescript is because sometimes you don't know better and the compiler can tell you if you make a mistake. If you always know better than the compiler why not just use javascript and not have to worry about those types at all?

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer somehow offended you in any way, it surely was not my intention. But your proposal it still not the answer on my question: "Why the TS-compiler accepts the cast as double cast or using the intermediate variable, but not on the direct way?" Going the same way using two steps instead of one is what I called "syntactical noise"

Comment: No offence taken. I've expanded my answer a bit though it still doesn't answer the fundamental 'is it a bug' part of your question.